Date Conversion | Power Automate
I am scheduling a flow to create a csv file and send an email to specific users.
flow I used: Recurrence --> Run Query against a dataset --> parse json --> create csv --> send an email (v2)
In my out csv file I have multiple columns in which few of them are date columns and default type for this date fields is 2024-07-05T00:00:00.
I want only date as '2024-07-05' instead of date time. Could somebody help me with this

a simple google search would have given you that answer.

You can use the formatDateTime function for this.
formatDateTime({yourDateProperty}, 'yyyy-MM-dd')

